# Разработка для Android (html, сss, java script) - ориентация

Tags: javascript, android, android-sdk, cordova

Как при разработке на площадках, поддерживающих html/сss/javascript, например таких, как **cordova/phonegap**, тестировать ориентацию экрана android?

Comment: Что подразумевается под тестировать?

Comment: @anber Верстка под экран, в горизонтальном положении - например, как поведут себя элементы. Или просто, используя браузер резиново. Почему спрашиваю, помню из курса где идет разработка на Java там что то вроде отдельных файликов layout горизонтально-вертикально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как поведут себя элементы

Для этого в Chrome есть специальная [утилита](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) для эмуляции мобильного браузера.

Вот [плагин](https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation), чтобы программно определять ориентацию в самом приложении.

Как на android по-умолчанию отдельных файликов для каждой ориентации нет.

Comment: Всем спасибо, впринципе так и думал, что в большей мере нужно расчитывать на резиновую верстку)

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, обычный браузер не сможет на 100% эмулировать мобильное устройство. Банально может быть несоответствие в шрифтах и пр. элементах. На cordova/phonegap нужно придерживаться основных правил резиновой html5- и css-верстки. Тогда есть вероятность, что на всех экранах приложение будет выглядеть более-менее нормально.

Comment: Ещё имеет смысл растровые картинки делать с большим в 2 раза разрешением, а то при увеличении размываются.

Answer (score 1):

Отлавливать изменение ориентации экрана можно, но обычно в этом нет необходимости. В Андроид есть разные xml файлы с разметками под разные ориентации, размеры экранов и плотность пикселов, но в phonegap идет разработка посути так же как под веб - CSS стили, HTML - если смениться ориентации все соответственно потянется. Более того можно использовать разные стили под разную ширину.